# Angular focus on page switch

Tags: angularjs, focus

I need to keep the focus on a specific input. Using autofocus html attribute it works fine at initial loading, but once I switch tab the focus is lost.

Do you know any way to force the focus ? something that I could integrate in $on('$stateChangeSuccess'  ?

Thanks a lot for your help !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom directive on input :

```
<input name="theInput" auto-focus>

app.directive('autoFocus', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AC',
        link: function(_scope, _element) {
                _element[0].focus();
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I tried but unfortunatelly it is executed only once !